# Send input form value to CSS style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

```css
    #target { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
    <form type="submit">
        <label for="width">Width</label>
        <input type="text" id="width" />
        <label for="height">Height</label>
        <input type="text" id="height"/>
        <button type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>

    <img id="target" src="URL" />
```

## SCENARIO

1. Insert a numerical value to `width` and `height` input form, and click `SEND`.
2. Value from `width` and `height` are inserted into `#target`'s CSS respectively.

I've googled around for some time, but I couldn't find any relevant solutions.

Comment: Not the solution but the `<input>` tag does not use or need a closing slash. Neither does `<img>`

Comment: Can you show us what have you have tried? I'm sure you managed to tried something

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `addEventListener('click')`.

```js
var send = document.querySelector('#send');

send.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var width = document.querySelector('#width').value;
  var height = document.querySelector('#height').value;
  var img = document.querySelector('#target');
  
  img.style.width = width+'px';
  img.style.height = height+'px';
});
```

```html
    <label for="width">Width</label>
    <input type="text" id="width" />
    <label for="height">Height</label>
    <input type="text" id="height"/>
    <button id="send">SEND</button>
    <br>
<img id="target" src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it answers the question.

Comment: @Rob When I need to explain, I usually use Google Translate. But It's not Efficient for me. Cause spent a lot of time and sometimes it made unreadable sentence. So, I usually skip explain my answer. Not always. If I think it deserve to explain, I did. But, in this question, I can't found to explain. I just suggest something, OP just judge. How can I explain at this Question?

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery .[click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/), [.val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) and [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) methods:

```
  $('button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
    $('#target').css('width', width);
    $('#target').css('height', height);
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do

```
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.style.width = submit.width.value;
target.style.height = submit.height.value;
```

This works, however it can fail if the user doesn't input *px* after the number.
To ensure this works, I would do this:

```js
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var valid = true;

        if (isNaN(parseInt(form.width.value.toLowerCase().replace("px", "")))) {
            document.getElementById("widthError").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid width";
            valid = false;
        }
        if (isNaN(parseInt(form.height.value.toLowerCase().replace("px", "")))) {
            document.getElementById("heightError").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid height";
            valid = false;
        }

        if (valid) {
            var target = document.getElementById("target");
            target.style.width = form.width.value.toLowerCase().replace("px", "") + "px";
            target.style.height = form.height.value.toLowerCase().replace("px", "") + "px";
        }
    })

    //If you have jQuery, which I HIGHLY recommend, you can use the code below:
    //$('#submit').click(function () {
    //    var valid = true;

    //    if (isNaN(parseInt($('#width').val().toLocaleLowerCase().replace("px", "")))) {
    //        $('#widthError').text("Please enter a valid width");
    //        valid = false;
    //    }
    //    if (isNaN(parseInt($('#height').val().toLocaleLowerCase().replace("px", "")))) {
    //        $('#heightError').text("Please enter a valid height");
    //        valid = false;
    //    }

    //    if (valid) {
    //        $("#target").css("width", $("#width").val().toLowerCase().replace("px", "") + "px").css("height", $("#height").val().toLowerCase().replace("px", "") + "px");
    //    }

    //})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="width">Width</label>
  <input type="text" id="width" />
  <span id="widthError" style="color:red; margin-right: 5px;"></span>
  <label for="height">Height</label>
  <input type="text" id="height" />
  <span id="heightError" style="color:red; margin-right: 5px;"></span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="submit" type="button">SEND</button>
</form>

<img id="target" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/839721704163155970/LI_TRk1z_400x400.jpg" />
```

Though my example is a bit crude, this will work in every scenario I can think of.

---

And, in case you are wondering, I do `.toLowerCase().replace("px","") + "px"` to ensure that the *px* part is added, otherwise the property will not take effect. If width is *94px* or *94*, it will remove the *px* part (and do nothing if there is no *px* part) to get *94* every time, then *px* is appended to get *94px*.

Answer (score 2):

jquery way 
[here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/rytdLya9/)

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
heightvalue=$('#height').val();
widthvalue=$('#width').val();
$('#target').css('width',widthvalue+'px').css('height',heightvalue+'px');
});
```

```css
#target{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="width">Width</label>
    <input type="text" id="width" />
    <label for="height">Height</label>
    <input type="text" id="height"/>
    <button id='submit'>SEND</button>


<div id="target">

</div>
```